# Browser got refreshing continuously while submitting a form in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

While submitting a form continuously i got a alert with the below message.

**"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."**

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to avoid this in the past and I believe it's not possible. This is because of the browser, it is asking if it should re-submit the $_POST and $_GET info.

As far as I know, it's not possible to avoid this, to avoid it you should just redirect to the URL, not refresh the page.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Forgot to say, if this helps, please approve this as an answer. :)